# How to detect the width and height of an Image?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have this ImageView, which fills the whole page. The image iteself is around 1/3 of it, and centered in the middleof the imageview.

How do you detect the width and height of the image, so that the ImageView can wrap around it instead of filling up the whole page?

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/picture" />
```

Comment: You don't need to, just set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Switch android:layout_height="fill_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

fill_parent (deprecated and renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher)

Setting the layout of a widget to fill_parent will force it to expand to take up as much space as is available within the layout element it's been placed in.

you can also set the size of the ImageView programmatically if thats where you know the size of the image.

```
image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
```

(Note) If you're setting the height after the layout has already been 'laid out', make sure you call image_view.requestLayout()